# Datepicker Clone ID Staying the Same on Add Row

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a SQL statement that prints out table rows in php, there may be 1 row or there may be 10 rows.  Each row has a datepicker in and currently the datepicker works on each row on its own.  However, when I click on the + icon at the end of a row to add a new row the datepicker doesn't pop up.  It seems to be assigning the same ID as the row before.  Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '#purchaseItems .add', function () {
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var clone = row.clone();

            // clear the values
            var tr = clone.closest('tr');
            tr.find('input[type=text]').val('');

            $(this).closest('tr').after(clone);
        });

        $(document).on('keypress', '#purchaseItems .next', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var v = $(this).index('input:text');
                var n = v + 1;
                $('input:text').eq(n).focus();
                //$(this).next().focus();
            }
        });
        $(document).on('keypress', '#purchaseItems .nextRow', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.add').trigger('click');
                $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input:first').focus();
            }
        });
        $(document).on('click', '#purchaseItems .removeRow', function () {
            if ($('#purchaseItems .add').length > 1) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            }
        });

        $('.datepicker').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
        });
    });
});
```

Table:

```
<table id="purchaseItems" name="purchaseItems" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Billable</th>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class='datepicker' name='from[]' value='$date' size='12'/></td>
        <td>
            <select name='billable[]'>
                <option value='$billable' selected>$billable</option>
                <option value='No'>No</option>
                <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type='text' name='client[]' value='$client' size='10'></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='$details' name='details[]' size='10'></td>
        <td><input type='button' name='addRow[]' class='add' value='+' /></td>
        <td><input type='button' name='addRow[]' class='removeRow' value='-' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So you can add rows fine, delete rows fine, change the rows that are currently there including the date.  The issue is when I press the + button, it adds the row but the datepicker doesn't pop up.

I know its to do with the id just cloning so I need a point in the right direction to change the id on clone row.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it:

```
   $(".datepicker").datepicker();

   $(document).on('click', '#purchaseItems .add', function () {



   $(".datepicker").datepicker("destroy");

    $(".datepicker").removeClass("hasDatepicker").removeAttr('id');


    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var clone = row.clone();



    // clear the values
    var tr = clone.closest('tr');
    tr.find('input[type=text]').val('');

    $(this).closest('tr').after(clone);

    $(".datepicker").datepicker();

});
```

Thank you if you had a look at it though.